# android mini pc connection on eclipse via USB not see from ADB devices command

Tags: android, debugging, adb

i want to install my app on a Android 4.0 mini pc (CHINESE). The problem is when i connect it to my pc over usb the laptop do not find any new devices. so well i can not debug my app

i also checked if usb debugging is enabled and if there are any drivers but i can't find anything useful.

perhaps anyone have had the same issue like me and can help?

I try with this cable (usbMINI-USB) but not working

from the OTG (MINIPC) to USB (pC)

---

> **Finally I got the solution**
>
> thanks I have the solution, changing the cable that brings by default
>   by other new ones, and download this drivers
>
> Allwinner A10 Drivers 
>   http://colonelzap.blogspot.com.ar/2012/01/allwinner-a10-adb-drivers.html
>
> Using the OTG device port  on the USB port.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If OTG in your question stands for OnTheGo USB cable - then you are using the wrong cable. OTG cable is used to connect USB peripherals to Android hosts. Use regular USB cable (not the OTG one) to connect your Android device to a PC.

[wikipedia article about USB OTG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go)

Comment: Do you mean that I have to connect the other usb connector available in the MINI PC ?. because is female connector, this means that I have to use a USB cable (male-male), this is the correct way to debugging the device?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a page with description of your device? Usually android devices have just 1 USB port which could be either regular (i.e. in slave mode for connecting to host PC) or universal - able to detect the inserted cable and select operation mode: slave or host(OTG). I have only seen dedicated OTG ports (if that's what you are trying to say your device has) on development boards before and never on production units. If that's the case - you need to use the other (not marked OTG) port for connecting to a host PC.

Comment: thanks I have the solution, changing the cable that brings by default by other new ones,

Comment: I have the same problem. Will a male to male usb cable work for debugging?